# Outlook VBA Accept Multiple Selected Meetings Not Auto Accept?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a need to select meetings in outlook and accept only the one i selected then delete them and do not send notification to the sender

so i was googling like always and i found batch  off information on how to do it, but surprise all of them is auto-accepts or 1 meeting per click

so i was trying to write it on my own, but i dont know VBA so mutch so crap it did not work hhh

here is the function i use:

```
        Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

this is working 100%

now the code to accept the meeting :

```
    Sub Accept()

Dim oAppt As MeetingItem
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim oRequest As MeetingItem

Dim oResponse

Set cAppt = GetCurrentItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
Set oRequest = GetCurrentItem()

Set oResponse = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
cAppt.UnRead = False
cAppt.Save
Set cItem = GetCurrentItem
cItem.Delete

Set cAppt = Nothing
Set oAppt = Nothing
Set oRequest = Nothing

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Accepted All Selected Meetings."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If

End Sub
```

now if i select one meeting it is working but for multiple selection at the same time it just work for the first item in the selected times

i try to do something like this:

```
    Sub Accept()

Dim oAppt As MeetingItem
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim oRequest As MeetingItem

Dim oResponse

Set cAppt = GetCurrentItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
Set oRequest = GetCurrentItem()

For i = oRequest To 1 Step -1
Set oResponse = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
cAppt.UnRead = False
cAppt.Save
Set cItem = GetCurrentItem
cItem.Delete
Next


Set cAppt = Nothing
Set oAppt = Nothing
Set oRequest = Nothing

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Accepted All Selected Meetings."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If

End Sub
```

but it dose not work :D

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in `Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)`

GetCurrentItem will return one item.

To run through all the items in the selection"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub IterateMultipleSelectedItems()

    Dim cItem As Object
    Dim i As Long

    ' Process multiple selected items
    For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.count To 1 Step -1

        Set cItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)

        If cItem.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
            Debug.Print cItem.Subject
            ' Accept code without GetCurrentItem
        End If

    Next

ExitRoutine:
    Set cItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Accept code replacing `GetCurrentItem` with `ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IterateMultipleSelectedItems2()

    Dim cItem As Object
    Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim oResponse As Object
    Dim i As Long

    ' Process multiple selected items
    For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.count To 1 Step -1

        Set cItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)

        If cItem.Class = olMeetingRequest Then

            Debug.Print cItem.Subject

            ' Accept code without GetCurrentItem
            Set cAppt = cItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            Set oResponse = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)

            cItem.unread = False
            cItem.Delete

            Set cAppt = Nothing

        End If

        Set cItem = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for the quick respond , but can i use it as an Function instead of a sub ?

i dont understand were to place it int he code ? like do i remove my  Function GetCurrentItem()

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
Option Explicit

 Sub IterateMultipleSelectedItems()

    Dim cItem As Object
    Dim i As Long

    ' Process multiple selected items
    For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set cItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)

        If cItem.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
            Debug.Print cItem.Subject
            ' Accept code without GetCurrentItem

                cItem = cItem.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
                cItem.UnRead = False
                cItem.Delete

                Set cItem = Nothing
                Set cItem = Nothing
                Set cItem = Nothing

                    If errorCode = 0 Then
                        'MsgBox "Accepted All Selected Meetings."
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
                    End If

        End If

    Next

ExitRoutine:
    Set cItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to replace the item you would get with GetCurrentItem, not just drop a line that uses GetCurrentItem. See my updated answer.

Comment: I did replace the GetCurrentItem

Comment: You dropped the `GetAssociatedAppointment` line. See the updated answer.

Comment: In a comment to my answer describe the result of using that code. Include error text if any. "does not work" is not useful information.